# Update array of objects using push method in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, multidimensional-array, angular6-json-schema-form

```js
studentsOld: any[] = [
   { id: 1, name : 'test', age: 20 }, 
   { id: 2, name : 'sample', age: 21 }
];
 
studentsNew: any = [];

tmp = 0;
selcatage;
funedit(post) {
  this.tmp = post.name
  this.selcatage = post.age
}

funsave() {
  this.studentsOld.forEach((item, index) => {
    var obj;
    obj = {
      name: item.name,
      age: item.age
    }
    
    this.studentsNew.push(obj)
    this.tmp = 0
    this.fundata()
  });
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.studentsNew))
}
```

I tried but not getting actual result. Is this correct way to push objects into new array

Sample output:

Update the `id:1`'s age 20 to 19 and display the value 19 and also show the same value 19 even after page refresh

Answer (score 0):

you not need to iterate
but only

```
this.studentsNew = this.studentsOld;

console.log(JSON.stringify(this.studentsNew));
```

but if you want to add a new data inside you can add on this way:

```
studentsOld: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name : 'test', age: 20 }, 
    { id: 2, name : 'sample', age: 21 }
 ];

 test(){
   this.studentsOld.push({
    id: 3, name : 'sample', age: 33
   })

   console.log("qui", this.studentsOld)
 }
```

Comment: i applied CRUD operations

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring to var obj, you can push directly to the array as below and subtract the age by 1 for your expected output:

```
studentsOld: any[] = [
   { id: 1, name : 'test', age: 20 }, 
   { id: 2, name : 'sample', age: 21 }
];
 
studentsNew: any = [];


funsave() {
  this.studentsOld.forEach((item, index) => {        
    this.studentsNew.push(obj)
    this.tmp = 0
    this.fundata({
      name: item.name,
      age: +item.age - 1
    })
  });
  
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.studentsNew))
}
```

This make work. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sandeep 905, I am glad you found my answer helpful :) If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark or up-voting it (once you have enough reputation to do so). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Thanks